# Flying a tour along a (KML) route and exporting frames

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-maps-api

I'm pretty new to the Earth Engine / GIS cosmos so please excuse my inexperience.

I'm working on a project for which I want to fly a virtual drone along a KML (or any GPS waypoint) route and export it as frames. (Basically exactly what Google Earth Pro's Movie Maker is made for – but in GE I can't control the saving so in my specific case it tries to safe 30.000.000 frames in one folder,... and ofc crashes. A couple of years ago I could have used the Google Earth API as a workaround but it's now discontinued.

Is it possible to fly along a KML route and export it with Google Earth Engine?

Comment: Looks like Google Earth tours might be what you are after https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148174?hl=en

Comment: That's what I'm already using but where I encounter problems with exporting / where I don't have any control about the saving..

Comment: Please remove the "google-earth-engine" tag, as this is a question for Google Earth (the popular exploration and visualization tool), and not Google Earth Engine (the advanced remote sensing analysis tool).

If you want to save a long video of a Google Earth fly-through, check out "Google Earth Studio", which may do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth Engine does not provide functionality for generating views from a camera viewpoint (or a series of viewpoints defined by a route).